# SendGrid send HTML Email using CURL and INCLUDE()

Tags: php, curl, sendgrid, php-curl

I am trying to send an HTML using CURL and SendGrid. I tried to install the SendGrid lib from GitHub and I could not figure it out to get the autoload.php correctly. I gave up on that and tried CURL. That worked for TEXT. I am able to send a TEXT email but not the HTML content from an include. I used to be able to do it before but they updated something in the API now it does not work.  Can someone please help me find what line I need to allow the HTML in the CURL with my own custom templated added from an INCLUDE?

```
  $url = 'https://api.sendgrid.com/'; 
    $pass = "MY-API-KEY"; 
    $template_id = 'my-Temp-ID';
    $js = array(
      'sub' => array(':name' => array('Mike Jakiner')),
      'filters' => array('templates' => array('settings' => array('enable' => 1, 'template_id' => $template_id)))
    );
    echo json_encode($js);
    /// I don't want to include a template but my own here.
    $Content = file_get_contents('custom/WelcomeHTML.php');
    $params = array(
        'to'        => "email@gmail.com", 
        'toname'    => "First Last Name",
        'from'      => "From@gmail.com",
        'fromname'  => "From Name",
        'subject'   => " LIVE EVENT", 
        'text'      => "Hoping this one works",
        'html'      => $Content,
        'x-smtpapi' => json_encode($js),
      );
    $request =  $url.'api/mail.send.json';
    $session = curl_init($request);
    curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, CURL_SSLVERSION_TLSv1_2);
    curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Authorization: Bearer ' . $pass));
    curl_setopt ($session, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt ($session, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $params);
    curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
    curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $response = curl_exec($session);
    curl_close($session);
    print_r($response);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, Just to be sure **echo $Content** to be sure your content is loaded properly from **custom/WelcomeHTML.php**

Second, since you are using your own HTML content, make sure that you don't include the **filters** section in your JSON request. The **filters** section is used for SendGrid template settings.

So remove this two lines from your code

```
$template_id = 'my-Temp-ID';

'filters' => array('templates' => array('settings' => array('enable' => 1, 'template_id' => $template_id)))
```

So your code should look like this:

```
$url = 'https://api.sendgrid.com/';
$pass = "MY-API-KEY";
$js = array(
    'sub' => array(':name' => array('Ed Vizenor'))
);
$Content = file_get_contents('custom/WelcomeHTML.php');

$params = array(
    'to'        => "email@gmail.com",
    'toname'    => "First Last Name",
    'from'      => "From@gmail.com",
    'fromname'  => "From Name",
    'subject'   => "LIVE EVENT",
    'text'      => "Hoping this one works",
    'html'      => $Content,
    'x-smtpapi' => json_encode($js),
);

$request =  $url.'api/mail.send.json';
$session = curl_init($request);
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, CURL_SSLVERSION_TLSv1_2);
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Authorization: Bearer ' . $pass));
curl_setopt ($session, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt ($session, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $params);
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$response = curl_exec($session);
curl_close($session);
print_r($response);
```

Comment: man, wow... you are the man! Thank you... Thank you... THANK YOU! Amazing. It works. I can't thank you enough.  :)  wow. So happy.

Comment: Glad you are so happy! An Upvote to the answer will be great! Cheers

Answer (score 2):

If you view the documentation at: https://docs.sendgrid.com/for-developers/sending-email/quickstart-php

It provides an excellent step by step instructions for getting setup.

With specific regard to the autoload, once you successfully run the composer require command, then you need to ensure your PHP file that you want to use for sendmail has the following include towards the top:

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php'
```

I would discourage you from simply writing your own cURL processor because it does not have the error handling that is provided in the official API.

Comment: I got the code working, however, I have never been able to get composer working with git. Just never done it before. That's why I could not get to the autoload. Do you recommend any video tutorials on how to use composer do download git projects so we can get the autoload.php? Thanks

Comment: Composer and GIt are not directly interchangeable. You can use composer to pull repos from git but only if git repository was built with composer in mind (ie a composer.json file exists) then it will not automatically wire it up for autoload.

Instead, you can look at [link]https://packagist.org/ to search for a library designed to be used with composer. Most people who publish PHP libraries to git that are designed to be run with composer will also publish them on packagist. If they're not listed there, then you'll need to basically wire up the PHP library from Git manually.

Comment: To be clear -- regarding sendgrid, there is ZERO need to touch the git repo itself, manually. Simply run the `composer require sendgrid/sendgrid` command as described in the documentation and include the `require 'vendor/autoload.php'` on the top of your code and you should be all set.